# Modify Grid created using XAML in code behind - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a cross platform Xamarin.Forms app. In a page, I've the following list view.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid x:Name="activityGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here as you can see I have one row and two columns for each item in the list view. the first label I've defined will be set in `Row=0` and `Column=0`, as that is the default. Now with respect to `Row=0` and `Column =1`, I want it to be a Switch or Entry based on some criteria. Here's my code behind.

```
foreach (var activity in activities)
{
    if (activity.Measurement == 0)
    {
        Switch yesNo = new Switch();
    }
    else
    {
        Entry measure = new Entry();
    }
}
```

Now help me add the children to the Grid Layout based on the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To add a control to a grid programatically, do this:

```
activityGrid.Children.Add(control, col, row);
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but was unsuccessful. It results in a error stating "The name 'activityGrid' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: ok, this approach won't work because your activityGrid is contained in a DataTemplate.  I'm not sure that a ListView is the right control to use for this case

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me! for some reason I was fixed on ListViews and couldn't think about anything else. But Now I realise My requirement is a finite list, most likely with in 10, so I can use StackLayout instead of ListView, but if I need a really long list, say 200, then what can I use.